# How to properly create a pdf with fpdf?

Tags: html, pdf, asp-classic, vbscript, fpdf

I have some code to  *try*  to create a single PDF document but i can't do it.

code :

```
<%@ language="vbscript"%>
<!--#include file="fpdf.asp"-->



<%
if Request.form("test") <> "" Then

    Set pdf=CreateJsObject("FPDF")
    pdf.CreatePDF()
    pdf.SetPath("fpdf/")
    pdf.SetFont "Arial","",16
    pdf.Open()
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.Cell 40,10,"Hello Word!"
    pdf.Close()

pdf.Output("list.pdf","T")

End If
%>
```

So, (dont mind with the request.form for execute..lol)
when i click the button i get : 
"FPDF error: Unable to create output file: list.pdf"
I've tried some sites for help and done alot of things and searched here on stack and found some useful things but nothing directed to this ...
Any help would be appreciated ! I can try to answer any questions you may have about the code or something else.
 **Also, if you have another solution for creating PDF's with classic ASP, please lemme know (free or  very low price)**
Thanks for your attention !

Comment: This might be an incredibly simple question, so I apologize in advance, but have you looked here? http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm

Comment: Sure i've Looked ! Also looked in the italian manual for ASP !

Comment: Oh wow. Okay, it's `pdf.Output("list.pdf","T")`

Comment: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0414' 
Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub 
pdf.Output("list.pdf","T")

Comment: Try `Call pdf.Output("list.pdf","T")`.

Comment: I put the "call" and i get the same error of the beggining    FPDF error: Unable to create output file: list.pdf

Comment: Hmmmmm. Try replacing `"T"` with `"F"`. Also, try putting `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` above the `.Output`.

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' 

Type mismatch: 'header'

Comment: Is this Vbscript ? also, i use the ~T~ to say that is true that i want to the user download the file instead of opening in his own brownser.

Comment: Ah okay. Yes it's VBS, but I'm not familiar with using ASP.

Comment: That's sad :/ im doing this for a very needed subject in my company ..... still searchin for solutions

Comment: Yes, it is sad. I need to expand my horizons a bit. Good luck on the issue, sorry I couldn't be of more help :\

Comment: No Problems ! Thanks for you help ... let's wait for someone to help ! hehe ty again

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but have you tried creating the PDF with a full path?

Comment: You say changing the .Output for a full path?

Comment: I mean did you try something like `"C:\temp\list.pdf"` instead of just `"list.pdf"`? Make sure that the folder exists and that the account running the ASP application has write access to that folder.

Comment: Hey thanks for tip @AnsgarWiechers but, still says that ~FPDF error: Unable to create output file~  C:\....list.pdf which I have access and the folder exists :/

Comment: The web application is not running under *your* account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've specified the path of Output to a VIRTUAL location and it Works great !
Thanks Every one for your help !
Best Regards